# Why are there excluded values for the positions of secondary maxima in $N$-slit interference?

Tags: optics, interference

My book gives the following formulae for the N-slit interference experiment:

[image: op]

My question is about the secondary maxima, the books says they happen when the numerator of the fraction in $I_R(\theta)$ is $I_1$, why is that?

Furthermore, it gives no explanation of why the followig values  $m''= N-1,N,....2N-1,2N,...$ are excluded.
It can't be those are the main maxima, because those occur when both the numerator and denominator of $I_R(\theta)$ are $0$, nor they can be minimum values, which happens when only the numerator is 0

How to prove these facts?

Comment: Please tell us which book you are referring to.

Comment: It's Fisica II by Mazzoldi,Nigro,Voci  It's an italian book

Answer (score 0):

> It can't be those are the main maxima, because those occur when both the numerator and denominator of $I_{\rm R}(\theta)$ are $0$, nor they can be minimum values, which happens when only the numerator is $0$.

To reconcile the $\frac 00$ dilemma for the positions of the maxima one has to find the value of the expression in a limit.

Let $\frac \delta 2 = \beta$ and so we need to find $\left(\dfrac{\sin N \beta}{\sin\beta} \right)^2$ when $\beta = n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer.

Let $\beta = n\pi +\epsilon$ so $$\left(\dfrac{\sin N \beta}{\sin\beta} \right)^2= \left(\dfrac{\sin N (n\pi + \epsilon)}{\sin (n\pi + \epsilon)} \right)^2= \left(\dfrac{\sin N \epsilon}{\sin\epsilon} \right)^2= N^2\left(\dfrac{\sin N \epsilon}{N\epsilon} \cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{\sin \epsilon} \right)^2$$

Now in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, $\dfrac {\sin \epsilon}{\epsilon}\to 1$ and $\dfrac {\sin N\epsilon}{N\epsilon}\to 1$ so at a maximum the intensity is proportional to $N^2$.

---

[image]

These relationships are a reasonably good **approximation** althought the subsidiary maximum are not actually located exacting in the middle between two minima.

If you differentiate your intensity equation with respect to $\beta$ you will find that the subsidiary maxima occur at values of $\beta$ which satisfy the equation $N\tan \beta = \tan N \beta$.

Comment: Do you say it is an approximation because they use the approximation for great distances? Anyway, how does this relate to the excluded values?

Comment: No the approximations are made to simplify matters as the actual positions of the subsidiary maxima are very near to the themid point between minima.  The positions where you have $\frac 00$ are the positions of the principal maxima.